# setting up win in the end of the game

Tags: java

I have a problem when i compile my code. I want to make my "Win" image to pop up when the score reaches 500 or over, but i get this error:

> "incompatible types: int cannot be converted to score"

The problem is under my "private void LevelUp"()"

Here is my code:

```
    import greenfoot.*;

/**
 * Write a description of class MinionWorld here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
    public class MinionWorld extends World
    {
    private long startMillis = 0;
    private int numFrames = 0;
    private final int groundHeight;

    public static final double MAX_FORCE = 11;
    public static final double MIN_FORCE = 7;
    public static final double GRAVITY = 0.15;
    public static final int LOWEST_ANGLE = 30;

    private Player[] players;
    private int curPlayer;
    private int turnCountdown;
    private int value; 

    Score score;
    Banan Banan;
    private int time, target;
    public static int poin, level;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Banana.
     * 
     */
    public MinionWorld()
    {    
        // Create a new world with 600x400 cells with a cell size of 1x1 pixels.
        super(800, 500, 1, false); 

        groundHeight = 440;

        players = new Player[] {new Minion()};
        int x = getWidth() / 2;

        for (Player p : players)
        {
            addObject(p, x, groundHeight);
        }
        curPlayer = 0;
        turnCountdown = 10;

        time = 1800;
        poin = 0;
        level = 1;
        target = 150;
        Greenfoot.setSpeed(50);
        prepare();
    }    


    private void showTime()
    {
        showText("Time: " + time/60, 700, 20);
    }    

    private void showTarget()
    {
        showText("Target: "+target, 714, 50);
    } 

    private void showLevel()
    {
        showText("Level: "+level, 50, 20);
    }  

    private void countTime()
    {
        showTime();
        if(time>0)
        {
            time--;
        }
        if (time == 0)
        {
            LevelUp();
        }   
    }

    private void lvup()
    {
        LvlUp LvlUp = new LvlUp();
        addObject(LvlUp,400,250);
        Greenfoot.delay(200);
        removeObject(LvlUp);
    }

    private void win()
    {
        Win Win = new Win();
        addObject(new Win(),400,250);
        Greenfoot.delay(200);
    }

    public void started()
    {
        numFrames = 0;
        startMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    private double t;

    public void act()
    {       
        numFrames += 1;
        t = getTimePerFrame();

        if (turnCountdown > 0)
        {
            turnCountdown -= 1;
            if (turnCountdown == 0)
            {
                players[curPlayer].startTurn();
            }
        }
        countTime();
        showTarget();
        showLevel();
    }

    public void changeScore(int nilai)
    {
      if(score!=null)
      {
          score.setScore(nilai);
      }
    }

    public double getTimePerFrame()
    {
        return (double)(System.currentTimeMillis() - startMillis) / (1000.0 * (double)(numFrames));
    }

    public boolean hitsGround(double startX, double startY, double endX, double endY)
    {
        return endY > groundHeight;
    }

    public void landed()
    {
        curPlayer = (curPlayer + 1) % players.length;
        turnCountdown = 10;
    }

    private void LevelUp()
    {
        {


            if(poin>=target)
            {
                level++;
                if (level==2)
                {
                    lvup();
                    time=1800;
                    target=350;
                }
                if (level==3)
                {
                    lvup();
                    time=1800;
                    target=500;

                }
            }
            else
                {
                    if (score = 500)
                    {
                        Greenfoot.stop();
                        addObject(new Win(), 400,200);
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        addObject(new GameOver(),400,200);
                        addObject(new TryAgain(),360, 320);
                        addObject(new Exit(),460,320);
                    }
                }
        }
    }

      /**
     * Prepare the world for the start of the program. That is: create the initial
     * objects and add them to the world.
     */
    private void prepare()
    {
        Menu Menu = new Menu();
        Greenfoot.setWorld(Menu); 
        score = new Score();

        Minion Minion = new Minion();
        addObject(Minion, 373, 435);
        Minion.setLocation(461, 400);
        removeObject(Minion);

        Evil1 evil1 = new Evil1();
        addObject(evil1, 697, 212);
        evil1.setLocation(577, 223);

        Evil2 evil2 = new Evil2();
        addObject(evil2, 259, 58);
        evil2.setLocation(695, 63);
        evil2.setLocation(693, 53);

        Evil3 evil3 = new Evil3();
        addObject(evil3, 742, 322);
        evil3.setLocation(575, 321);
        evil3.setLocation(323, 305);
        evil3.setLocation(573, 319);

        Evil4 evil4 = new Evil4();
        addObject(evil4, 92, 117);
        evil4.setLocation(92, 111);

        Score score = new Score();
        addObject(score, (697), 168);
        score.setLocation(757, 247);
        score.setLocation(561, 163);
        score.setLocation(463, 124);
    }
}
```

Here is my code for my Score class:

```
import greenfoot.*;


public class Score extends Actor
{
/**
 * Act - do whatever the Score wants to do. This method is called whenever
 * the 'Act' or 'Run' button gets pressed in the environment.
 */
public Score(){
    GreenfootImage gfi = new GreenfootImage(200,200);
    gfi.setColor(java.awt.Color.white);
    gfi.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Las Vegas",java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 36));
    gfi.drawString("0", 30, 30);
    setImage(gfi);
}

public void setScore(int score) 
{
    GreenfootImage gfi = getImage();
    gfi.clear();
    gfi.drawString(score + "", 30,30);
    setImage(gfi);
}    

//just a little settlement
public void act()
{
    if(MinionWorld.poin>9)
    {
        setLocation(445, getY());
    }
}
}
```

Code for "move" class:

```
 import greenfoot.*;

/**
 * Write a description of class Move here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
    public class Move extends Actor
{
    int q = 0;
    private int Evil = 0;
/**
 * Act - do whatever the Fly wants to do. This method is called whenever
 * the 'Act' or 'Run' button gets pressed in the environment.
 */
public void act() 
{

}    
public void flyy()
{
    if (getX() == 0 || getX() == 799)
    {
        setLocation(getX(), 50+Greenfoot.getRandomNumber(320));
        turn(180);
        this.getImage().mirrorVertically();
        q++;
    }
}
public void right()
{
    move(3/2);
}
public void left()
{
    move(-3/2);
}
public void touch1()
{
    if(isTouching(Banan.class))
     {
        MinionWorld MinionWorld = (MinionWorld) getWorld();
        MinionWorld.poin = MinionWorld.poin + 10;
        MinionWorld.changeScore(MinionWorld.poin);
        removeTouching(Evil1.class);
        setLocation(799, 50+Greenfoot.getRandomNumber(320));
        left();
     }
}
public void touch2()
{
    if(isTouching(Banan.class))
    {    
        MinionWorld MinionWorld = (MinionWorld) getWorld();
         MinionWorld.poin = MinionWorld.poin + 10;
        MinionWorld.changeScore(MinionWorld.poin);
        removeTouching(Evil2.class);
        setLocation(0, 50+Greenfoot.getRandomNumber(320));
        right();
    }
}
public void touch3()
{
    if(isTouching(Banan.class))
    {    
        MinionWorld MinionWorld = (MinionWorld) getWorld();
        MinionWorld.poin = MinionWorld.poin + 10;
        MinionWorld.changeScore(MinionWorld.poin);
        removeTouching(Evil3.class);
        setLocation(799, 50+Greenfoot.getRandomNumber(320));
        left();
    }
}
public void touch4()
{
    if(isTouching(Banan.class))
    {
        MinionWorld MinionWorld = (MinionWorld) getWorld();
        MinionWorld.poin = MinionWorld.poin + 10;
        MinionWorld.changeScore(MinionWorld.poin);
        removeTouching(Evil4.class);
        setLocation(0, 50+Greenfoot.getRandomNumber(320));
        right();
    }
}

public void nulled2()
{
    if (getWorld().getObjects(Evil2.class).isEmpty())
    {
        getWorld().addObject(new Evil2(), 0, 50+Greenfoot.getRandomNumber(320));
        right();
    }
}
public void nulled4()
{
    if (getWorld().getObjects(Evil4.class).isEmpty())
    {
        getWorld().addObject(new Evil4(), 0, 50+Greenfoot.getRandomNumber(320));
        right();
    }
}

public void flyback1()
{       
   if(getX()<-15)
    {
        setLocation(800, 50+Greenfoot.getRandomNumber(320));
    }
   if(getX()>815)
   {
        setLocation(799, 50+Greenfoot.getRandomNumber(320));
        turn(180);
        this.getImage().mirrorVertically();
   }
}

public void flyback2()
{       
   if(getX()<-35)
    {
        setLocation(0, 50+Greenfoot.getRandomNumber(320));
        turn(180);
        this.getImage().mirrorVertically();
    }
   if(getX()>834)
   {
       setLocation(0, 50+Greenfoot.getRandomNumber(320));
   }
}  
}
```

Comment: The problem is here: `if (score = 500)`. Other than missing an extra `=`, you are trying to compare a custom object to a number, which is failing. Without knowing what `Score` is it is difficult to tell.

Comment: Quite a lot of irrelevant code here. We'd need to see the `Score` class and the line of code that doesn't work.

Comment: I have have put in the code for my score class

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit too long for a comment so I'll post it here.

You are most likely missing the following:

1. A `field` in your `Score` class.
2. A `getter` for that field`.
3. Fixing `if (score = 500)` and changing it to `if (score.getScore() == 500)`.

So basically:

```
public class Score extends Actor {
    private int score;

    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
        ...
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return this.score;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a score field. Your class should be like this:

```
public class Score extends Actor
{

private int score;

public int getScore(){
   return score;
}
/**
 * Act - do whatever the Score wants to do. This method is called whenever
 * the 'Act' or 'Run' button gets pressed in the environment.
 */
public Score(){
    GreenfootImage gfi = new GreenfootImage(200,200);
    gfi.setColor(java.awt.Color.white);
    gfi.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Las Vegas",java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 36));
    gfi.drawString("0", 30, 30);
    setImage(gfi);
}

public void setScore(int score) 
{
    GreenfootImage gfi = getImage();
    gfi.clear();
    this.score += score;
    gfi.drawString(this.score + "", 30,30);
    setImage(gfi);
}    

//just a little settlement
public void act()
{
    if(MinionWorld.poin>9)
    {
        setLocation(445, getY());
    }
}
}
```

Then your if should be:

```
if(score.getScore() == 500){
//doStuff
}
```

Comment: I've modified the setScore() method in the answer. Check it out and let me know if this fixes it. I've just added this line: this.score += score;

Comment: Sorry you also have to change the next instruction into gfi.drawString(this.score + "", 30,30);

Comment: Ok, I am just assuming that you are counting the score in the method setScore(). Is that right?

Comment: yes i think, but i also have something with score in my "move" which is the object you are supposed to hit for getting points. i have just put the code for my "move" class in. But i haven't done anything with that since i asked my question in here.

Comment: Your move class may need some modification in order to work with the new score. Do you mind posting the code?

Comment: i think i have posted it in your answer you made earlier ;)

Comment: Yeah let me put that in the question first, then I'll check it :D

Comment: Super! i hope you can help :D

Comment: That seems very odd... Your code seems right to me... Are you sure you added this line: 

private int score;
in your Score class?

Comment: I think I need a little bit more information... What do you exactly mean with score count? Did your score counted before the edits? With the edit we made to the program, nothing should have changed...

Comment: yes, my score counted before the edits, that is what i don't understand.. i have looked it all through and i don't know what is wrong

Comment: Can you remove the modification we made step-by-step and try to identify where exactly is the problem?